# Vulkan Memory Allocator c interface issue

Tags: c, vulkan

I have included vk_mem_alloc.h on my c project and in my cmake file i added it as an interface like this

```
add_library(include INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(include INTERFACE include)
```

while include is the folder where i put my vma header file
and i added it without `#define VMA_IMPLEMENTATION` as mention in documentation like this

```
#include "include/vk_mem_alloc.h"
```

and yet it always gives me

```
undefined reference to 'vmaCreateAllocator'
```

when i try to initialize it

im using fedora 37 with vulkan 1.3

Comment: Have you configured linking VMA in cmake?

Comment: can you be more specific ?

Comment: it looks that VMA was not **linked** to your program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)